# How to call a void function with a struct pointer as parameter in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference

**All I really need is just examples on how to return these kind of functions to it's caller. Doesn't even have to relate to my code except for the type of function and parameter.**

I wrote this function below that is supposed to read the name and age of three user defined people.

```
void readData(Person *p) 
{
    char name1[20], name2[20], name3[20];
    int age1, age2, age3;
    printf("Enter person 1: \n");
    scanf("%s %d", &name1, &age1);
    printf("Enter person 2: \n");
    scanf("%s %d", &name2, &age2);
    printf("Enter person 3: \n");
    scanf("%s %d", &name3, &age3);
    struct person1 {char name1[20]; int age1};
    struct person2 {char name2[20]; int age2};
    struct person3 {char name3[20]; int age3};
    struct Person {struct person1; struct person2; struct person3};
    struct Person man[3] = {{name1, age1}, {name2, age2}, {name3, age3}};
    p = &man;
}
```

I would like to re-use the variables of the above function so that I can use it in the function below. How am I supposed to do that as I cannot 're-declare' the variables because they are user-defined? Do I call by reference or value and if so, how do I do that? Do I need to `return` anything? I can't find examples for this kind of functions, any help is really appreciated.

```
Person findMiddleAge(Person *p) 
{
    int middle;
    if ((age1 < age2 && age2 < age3) || (age3 < age2 && age2 < age1)) {
        middle = age2;
        struct Person man[1] = {name2, age2};
        }
    else if ((age2 < age1 && age1 < age3) || (age3 < age1 && age1 < age2)) {
            middle = age1; 
            struct Person man[1] = {name1, age1};
            }
    else if ((age1 < age3 && age3 < age2) || (age2 < age3 && age3 < age1)) {
        middle = age3;
        struct Person man[1] = {name3, age3};
        }
    printf("%d \n", middle);
}
```

The chunk of code below shows my whole code just in case it matters. **Nothing can be amended except for the lines of code within the `readData(Person *p)` and `Person findMiddleAge(Person *p)` functions.**

```
typedef struct {
   char name[20]; 
   int age;
} Person; 

void readData(Person *p);
Person findMiddleAge(Person *p);
int main() 
{
   Person man[3], middle;   

   readData(man);
   middle = findMiddleAge(man);
   printf("findMiddleAge(): %s %d\n", middle.name, middle.age);
   return 0;
}

void readData(Person *p) 
{
    char name1[20], name2[20], name3[20];
    int age1, age2, age3;
    printf("Enter person 1: \n");
    scanf("%s %d", &name1, &age1);
    printf("Enter person 2: \n");
    scanf("%s %d", &name2, &age2);
    printf("Enter person 3: \n");
    scanf("%s %d", &name3, &age3);
    struct person1 {char name1[20]; int age1};
    struct person2 {char name2[20]; int age2};
    struct person3 {char name3[20]; int age3};
    struct Person {struct person1; struct person2; struct person3};
    struct Person man[3] = {{name1, age1}, {name2, age2}, {name3, age3}};
    p = &man;
}

Person findMiddleAge(Person *p) 
{
    int middle;
    if ((age1 < age2 && age2 < age3) || (age3 < age2 && age2 < age1)) {
        middle = age2;
        struct Person man[1] = {name2, age2};
        }
    else if ((age2 < age1 && age1 < age3) || (age3 < age1 && age1 < age2)) {
            middle = age1; 
            struct Person man[1] = {name1, age1};
            }
    else if ((age1 < age3 && age3 < age2) || (age2 < age3 && age3 < age1)) {
        middle = age3;
        struct Person man[1] = {name3, age3};
        }
    printf("%d \n", middle);
}
```

And yes, this is homework but I really tried my best (I tried over 6 hours to get the desired results but I still can't, C is really hard for me to understand). I am supposed to find the person whose age is the middle of the three people, and return the name and age of that person to the caller. Am I going about everything incorrectly? I actually just want to know how to return this kind of functions to the caller. Do I need to put any `return` statements? I can't find examples on it (if anyone has any examples, I think I can figure the code out myself with those examples)?

Thank you for any help in advance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can just pass each person as an argument `Person* findMiddleAge(Person* first, Person* second, Person* third)` or pass an array of Person.

Comment: Maybe consider `*p = man;` in place of `p = &man;` - do you really want the address of a local variable?

Comment: Your `readData` function doesn't really work -- assigning an address (`&man`) to variable `p` has no effect outside of the function because `p` was passed to the function by value -- whatever variable that you think was supposed to receive the address, is unchanged.

Comment: @AdrianMole I cannot do that, they are of different types... there will be error: incompatible types when assigning to type Person {aka struct } from type struct Person

Comment: @amn actually I am a bit confused by the pointer *p, how am I supposed to return the function to the caller if I cannot assign the desired outcome to it? Isn't it supposed to be call by reference? Any suggestions on how to return the function?

Comment: What do you mean by "return the function"? Returning functions in C is something completely different from what you ask for here, arguably. Functions in C *only* return values, however these values may be of different type, including an address (a pointer). Through using these pointers you can write any variable, inside or outside the function because the program can access the same memory regardless of which function is being called. Except of course if the address is somewhere on the stack that isn't valid anymore. I recommend you think in terms of memory content and addresses.

Comment: @amn I just meant that, by 'returning the function', I want to to be able to 'call' the values assigned to the variables in the function so that I can use in another function without redefining them as they are all user-defined. The type doesn't matter (I can work around that), I just want to get those values so that the error 'not defined' will stop appearing in the other function and I did not want to use global to do that. But it's alright, I now know what my problem was, I just didn't really understood how `typedef ` works. But if there is a suggestion to 'return values', pls do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `readData` and `findMiddleAge` `p` points to `man[3]` in `main`.
In `readData` the array may be filled directly. It is a good habit to check the return of `scanf`. If name and age are scanned, it will return 2. A return of 1, 0 or EOF indicates a problem.
In `findMiddleAge` determine which is the middle value of `p[0].age`, `p[1].age` or `p[2].age` and return the correct one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int age;
} Person;

void readData(Person *p);
Person findMiddleAge(Person *p);

int main()
{
    Person man[3] = { { "", 0}}, middle = { "", 0};

    readData(man);
    middle = findMiddleAge(man);
    printf("findMiddleAge(): %s %d\n", middle.name, middle.age);
    return 0;
}

void readData(Person *p)
{
    printf("Enter person 1: \n");
    scanf("%19s %d", p[0].name, &p[0].age);
    printf("Enter person 2: \n");
    scanf("%19s %d", p[1].name, &p[1].age);
    printf("Enter person 3: \n");
    scanf("%19s %d", p[2].name, &p[2].age);
}

Person findMiddleAge(Person *p)
{
    //figure out which is the middle value of
    //p[0].age
    //p[1].age
    //p[2].age
    return p[1];//or p[0] or p[2]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am unsure how it works though. For the  `scanf("%19s %d", p[0].name, &p[0].age)`  , does the p[0].name also need & in front? If not, why? Based on the code, am I correct in thinking that once I assign something `*p` to `in void readData(Person *p)` function, it also applies to `*p` in another function such as in `findMiddleAge(Person *p)`?

Comment: Also, I am not very sure what `Person findMiddleAge(Person *p)` does. It is not related to this question that I posted, but if you don't mind explaining, is it actually a struct or a function or both or something else. Because it starts with `Person`, I am confused because I thought a function is supposed to start with a data type like int, char or void?

Comment: One final question, what are the differences between `Person man[3], middle` and  `Person man[3] = { { "", 0}}, middle = { "", 0}`?

Comment: Your suggestion to use `p[i]` worked beautifully! Thanks a lot for that and for answering all my queries! I think I have a better idea of how functions work now. Really, thanks for all the clarifications.

Comment: I did not even think of using just `p[i]` because I saw the word `struct` and kept trying to use `struct` within the other functions. Now, I realised since Person has been defined as struct type, I have been going about this the wrong way. Once again, thanks!

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to write `void readData(Person *p) { for(Person *e = p+3; p<e; p++) scanf("%19s %d", p->name, &p->age);}`, but you still *must* check the value returned from scanf.

Answer (score 0):

In one line you have two problems:

```
p = &man
```

1. You assign pointer to the local variable (and dereference it after the function return) which is the UB.
2. You assign local pointer `p` and this assignment does not make any effect (as `p` stops to exist when function returns). To modify the pointer itself you need to pass pointer to pointer.

```
void readData(Person **p) 
{
    /* ... */
    *p = newpvalue;
}
```

I believe there is much more similar problems in your code. I advice to focus on the C basics (scopes, variables, pointers etc.)

Comment: Thanks! I realised that now, it was really a last ditch attempt to call the function by reference. And I will brushed up on the basics. What I failed to realise about the code is that since Person was already defined as a struct type, there was really no need for me to do stuff like this: `struct person1 {char name1[20]; int age1};`. I just didn't really understand how `typedef` work and thought `Person` is still also a variable.

Comment: @user3121023 where you see in my pseudo code the `man` ? Why do you comment something which does not exist

Comment: @user3121023 But it is not in my answer. So how the comment is related to the answer?